# Is there a way I can solve this issue because the password field is not defined in the MobileCustomer class?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, abstract-class, django-custom-user

```
class MobileCustomer(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
        contact = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
        user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
            Permission,
            verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
            blank=True,
            help_text=_('The permissions this user has'),
            related_name='mobileuser_set'  # Add a unique related_name
        )

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('username',)

        objects = MobileUserManager()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
```

I have this class up but when I try to migrate it gives me an error:
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'password' to mobilecustomer without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py

Comment: Did you just recently add the inheritance of `AbstractUser`? Did you store some `MobileCustomer` objects already with a model field called `password`? If you don't care about the data one possible version is to delete the database and migrations, then `makemigrations` and `migrate` again and you should be fine. Let me know your answers.

Comment: I removed the MobileCustomer model and added a boolean field to the CustomUser .
Thank you for reaching out to help.

Comment: Does your database already contain `MobileCustomer` objects, or is the database empty? In case it is a populated database: Can you delete the data, or is this of importance for you?